# Margin out of nowhere on React Next + tailwind

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I started my first project with create next app after using create react app for years and I just noticed something strange. After using a router link (router.push("/main");) I get a white margin around the showing page/component. I have played around in order to delete it but I have no clue what is making the  tag to have a margin:8px property.
So far I get:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto sm:max-w-none md:max-w-sm lg:max-w-xl xl:max-w-2xl"> 
      <Login/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

// here the login component

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { myFetch } from "./myFetch";

export default function Login() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("user", user);
    formData.append("password", password);

    try {
      const response = await myFetch("url", formData);
      router.push("/main");
      // Verifica el estado de la respuesta
      if (response.ok) {
      } else {
        console.error("Error al iniciar sesión");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error de red:", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col" style={{ background: "repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,#2a2c3d,#2a2c3d 10px,#242529 10px,#242529 20px)" }}>
      <div className="mt-0 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
        <div className="bg-white py-4 px-4 shadow rounded-xl sm:px-10 mx-10">
          <h2 className="mt-2 text-center pb-4 text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900">Inicio de sesión</h2>
          <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST">
           // content of form
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And when pressing the button it goes to home component, which is wrapped on a basic layout I'm starting to reuse later:

```
const BasicLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen min-h-screen max-h-screen w-full flex flex-col" style={{ background: "repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,#2a2c3d,#2a2c3d 10px,#242529 10px,#242529 20px)" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <BasicLayout>
      <div className="bg-white py-4 px-4 shadow rounded-xl sm:px-10 mx-10">
        <div>main example text</div>
      </div>
    </BasicLayout>
  );
};
```

It doesn't seem either to apply the  styles as "bg-white".

Answer (score 0):

Well It seems that the solution is more complicated that one can guess.

First you have to create a file in the pages folder. The file name must be `_app.js`

Then paste the following content in the file:

```
import "../app/globals.css";
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return <Component {...pageProps} />    
   }
```

Take into account the path to your css file or globals.css file.
This will make tailwork to work into the components in this directory and you won't need to apply the import on each individual file. I don't know the reason for this, but extrangely it worked for me.